# C# - idea behind instantiating BitMap object twice to avoid locking problems

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, dispose

I had a problem with deleting image that was opened in a `PictureBox`. Thanks to `Hans Passant` I got a solution for this problem using this snippet proposed by him :

```
            using (var temp = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(temp);
            }
```

I tried to crash the code but I couldn't so it seems to work, but I don't quite understand the logic behind this code. Before I was doing :

```
if (MyImage != null)
                    {
                        MyImage.Dispose();

                    }
...
MyImage = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    pictureBox1.Image = (Image)MyImage;
```

which even very rare caused a problem with `resource being used`.

Why this not happen in the new code that I'm using. I ask this in order to understand what happens under the cover. I know that `using` guarantees that `Dispose()` will be called but `Disposed()` is called in the previous code as well. Most of the time the resource is released fast enough but what what is the big difference that allows the new code to release the image **always** fast enough so it could be deleted or whatever we need to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `Bitmap` object from a file, it will keep the file open as long as the `Bitmap` object exists.

In your original code you are using the `Bitmap` object opened from the file in the control, so as long as the control shows the image, the file will be open.

In the new code a new `Bitmap` object is created by copying the data from the `Bitmap` object that was created from the file. The new `Bitmap` object doesn't copy the connection to the file, so when you dispose the first `Bitmap` object the file will be closed.

A solution that uses a bit less resources would be to read the data from the file into a byte array, create a memory stream from that and use that to create the image:

```
using (var m = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName))) {
  pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(m);
}
```

Comment: But this again depends on when the GC will do his job, doesn't it? And as I read already in countless articles there is no guarantee that it will be milliseconds or minutes before that happens. Is there any logical reason for the fact the the new code release the resource a lot faster than my previous one apart from the fact that the resource is ready for disposing almost immediately. The way I understood how GC works this still doesn't mean that the resource will be unlocked at a particular time.

Comment: @Leron: No, the purpose for the GC is to collect managed resources. The file handle is an unmanaged resource, and that is removed when the object is disposed. After the object is disposed, there are no connections to any system resources, so it's just a piece of unused memory that can be collected later on. (If you don't dispose an object properly before releasing it, the GC has to finalize it (which calls dispose) before it can be collected.)

Comment: @Leron: When the `using` block exits, it will *immediately* tell the first bitmap that it is no longer needed.  This will cause the bitmap to immediately tell the file that it is no longer needed.  These actions are in no way dependent upon the garbage collector.  Further, even if the GC could magically always trigger whenever any object was no longer needed, it's possible that the code's need for a bitmap holding the proper pattern of pixels might last awhile.  If the pixel data weren't copied to a new object, the file couldn't be closed while the picture was still needed.

Comment: why copy it into a memstream? wouldn't `using(var stream = openFileDialog1.OpenStream())` suffice?

Comment: @Firo: No, then you are back where you started. Opening the image from a file stream will keep the file open as long as the `Bitmap` object exists.

Comment: does `Image.FromStream` really test for FileStream? if so just wrap the stream in BufferedStream or something. I wanted to point out that copying twice (1. ReadAllBytes and 2. FromStream) is not very efficient